# definition of derivative for complex analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

How can I use the definition of derivative to find the derivative of $\dfrac{\bar{z}^2}{z}$.

My attempt, $\dfrac{\dfrac{\overline{z+\Delta z}^2}{z+\Delta z}-\dfrac{\bar{z}}{z}^2}{\Delta z}= \dfrac{z\bigg(\overline{z+\Delta z\bigg)}^2-\bar{z}^2\bigg(\overline{z+\Delta z}\bigg)}{\Delta z\cdot z\cdot (z+\Delta z)} $.

This is where I get stuck no idea how to break this down...

Comment: First write the function as $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. Then write $\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta z}$ in the form $a+bi$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have written is not analytic and can't be differentiated. The reason is that it does not follow Cauchy-Riemann conditions. In other words, on a complex plane, the derivative of a function only exists if the derivative doesn't change depending on which direction we approach the lim $\Delta z $ tends to zero. To see if a function verifies CR conditions, we write it in the form of $z=x+iy. $ You can refer any standard text for the theory. I refer to Weber Arfken and Harris. 
Note that this is a special class of functions which are continuous on complex plane, yet not differentiable.